# Adjusting size of <canvas> to fit parent div while still maintaining draw functionality - help needed

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, canvas

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './app.css'

function App() {

  const canvasRef = useRef(null)
  const contextRef = useRef(null)
  const divRef = useRef(null)
  const [isDrawing, setIsDrawing] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current
    canvas.width = divRef.clientWidth * 2;
    canvas.height = divRef.clientHeight * 2;
    canvas.style.width = `${divRef.clientWidth}px`;
    canvas.style.height = `${divRef.clientHeight}px`;

    const context = canvas.getContext("2d")
    context.scale(2,2)
    context.lineCap = "round"
    //this line will provide the color - maybe change that to let users type in a color or click a color
    context.strokeStyle = "black"
    //here the line thickness is defined
    context.lineWidth = 5
    contextRef.current = context
  }, [])

  const startDrawing = ({nativeEvent}) => {
    const {offsetX, offsetY} = nativeEvent
    contextRef.current.beginPath()
    contextRef.current.moveTo(offsetX, offsetY)
    setIsDrawing(true)
  }

  const finishDrawing = () => {
    contextRef.current.closePath()
    setIsDrawing(false)
  }

  const draw = ({nativeEvent}) => {
    if(!isDrawing){
      return
    }
    const {offsetX, offsetY} = nativeEvent;
    contextRef.current.lineTo(offsetX, offsetY)
    contextRef.current.stroke()
  }

  return (
    <div id="canvasDiv" ref={divRef}>
      <canvas
        onMouseDown={startDrawing}
        onMouseUp={finishDrawing}
        onMouseMove={draw}
        ref={canvasRef}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

```
#canvasDiv {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: black;
}

#canvasDiv canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Having trouble getting my draw application to work within the confines of the parent div. It does manage to resize the canvas but at the expense of the draw functionality no longer working. The code below is how it looks when it works using the entire view window as the canvas, but I am trying to implement it into a moveable window and need to be able to resize it.

```
const canvas = canvasRef.current
canvas.width = window.innerWidth * 2;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight * 2;
canvas.style.width = `${window.innerWidth}px`;
canvas.style.height = `${window.innerHeight}px`;
```

Comment: **Do not ever set a canvas size through CSS**. It **never** works. Use HTML instead: `<canvas width="500" height="500">`. Also, pixels are the only valid option for a `canvas` everything else scales it.

Comment: Yea I just had that in there to test it hoping that it would take the size of the parent div that I have for it. However, using inline styling is also being overridden and not working.

Comment: Could you share a link where I could take a look

Comment: Oh I think I figured it out, I had to change canvas.style.width & canvas.style.height to `${1000}px` & `${750}px` (both of those surrounded by backticks) respectively and then mess with the context.scale to get the cursor to line up correctly with the draw functionality